# Springboot jpa : Entity can't bind data from custom query that's not in table column

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, mapping, entity

I use java Springboot JPA, mysql.

I need to get data from my custom query and some of the data (nextBno, beforeBno, etc) are not DB table column. They are from my query like below:

```
            (
                    SELECT boardNo FROM table_news
                    WHERE boardNo IN (
                        SELECT MIN(boardNo)
                        FROM table_news A
                        WHERE status=0 AND boardNo > 65
                    )
                ) AS nextBNo,
```

---

So when I fetch data from the query, data fetch well because query itself is fine. but result is is filled as `null`.
I think I should fix something from JPA Model(Entity) file so that the data can bind well but don't know exactly how.
I tried to add @Transient annotation but it doesn't seem to work.

NewsModel.java

```
@Data 
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_news")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
public class NewsModel {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "boardNo")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer boardNo;

   (...)

    @Transient
    private Integer nextBNo;
    @Transient
    private Integer beforeBNo;
    
    (...)
}
```

NewsResponse.java

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class NewsResponse {

    private Integer boardNo;

    (...)

    @Transient
    private Integer nextBNo;
    @Transient
    private Integer beforeBNo;

    (...)

    public NewsResponse(NewsModel model){
        this.boardNo = model.getBoardNo();
 
        (...)
        this.nextBNo = model.getNextBNo();
        this.beforeBNo = model.getBeforeBNo();

    }
```

NewsRepository.java -- interface

```
@Repository
public interface NewsRepository extends JpaRepository<NewsModel, Integer> {

    @Query(value = "(MY CUSTOM QUERY)", nativeQuery = true)
    NewsModel getNewsWithNextAndBefore(Integer boardNo);
}
```

Comment: Try using this jpa query, select model.boardNo from NewsModel model where model.boardNo in (select min(m.boardNo) from NewModel m where m.status = 0 and m.boardNo > 65), the return type is Integer and not NewsModel and delete nativeQuery param

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried mentioning the "Schema" name under the Entity class? Maybe table is not getting mapped properly, that could be a problem.